# Can the noun »Süße« be neuter?

Tags: gender, article

The article “[Caffè-Nostalgie in Italien. Komm doch, Starbucks.](http://www.spiegel.de/reise/staedte/italien-und-seine-caffe-nostalgie-starbucks-kann-ruhig-kommen-a-1140862.html)” from *Der Spiegel* lists and describes famous cafés in Italy, among other things. A portion of one such description reads (my question refers to the title of the description only):

> **Caffè Gilli in Florenz: *Das Süße***
>
> Die Glastheke mit Eclairs, bunten Obsttörtchen und Petit fours des
>   Caffè Gilli in Florenz scheint kein Ende zu nehmen. Auf Pasticceria,
>   also Konditoreiwaren, ist dieses Haus seit seiner Gründung 1733
>   spezialisiert. Schließlich waren seine Gründer Feinbäcker aus der
>   Schweiz.

Why is *Süße* neuter in the title above?

According to [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=S%C3%BC%C3%9Fe), *Süße* can be only either feminine or masculine:

> NOUN 1:   der Süße/ein Süßer (Pl.: die Süßen)
>
> NOUN 2:   die Süße [das Süßsein; die süße Art] (kein Plural)
>
> NOUN 3:   die Süße [Mädchen, (junge) Frau] (Pl.: die Süßen)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because here, das Süße, is a nominalization ("Substantivierung") of the adjective süß, which in principle can have any article.

There can be two reasons (thanks to  @KilianFoth for pointing out one of them) for the article "das" here:

- "Das" could refer to **das** Cafè. Other articles are possible, for instance if the place was a bakery (der Bäcker) it could be called "Der Süße".
- It could refer to the sensation of sweetness rather than to the place/Cafè. In that case it has to be neuter (which is the usual case for nominalization of adjectives of non-living, uncountable things).

From the context given it is unclear whether one or both are meant here.

Comment: It should be added that the gender of nominalizations only follows the gender of the noun if there *is* a noun involved! If you're talking about abstract concepts, e.g. expressed as a subclause, then the neuter is in fact *mandatory*:  "*Das Gute* an Regeln ist, dass sie Ausnahmen haben." - "Das Süße zieht den Menschen unwiderstehlich an." The name might refer to the sensation of sweetness itself rather than the café.